# Acessing struct data from another struct

Tags: c

I am trying to access data of one node from another node.

```
struct orderNode 
{
  int price;
  int quantity;
};

struct lnode
{
  struct lnode* data;
  struct lnode* next;
  struct lnode* prev;
};
```

how can i use lnode value (data) to access the values (price and quantity).

Comment: There is no `orderNode` inside the `lnode` struct, I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: That is the question, how will you access the value of orderNode using lnode.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand what a struct is? Those are simply definitions; you haven't made anything yet. Later you can create as many `lnode`s and `orderNode`s as you like. You can then access the price / quantity of a *specific* orderNode.

Comment: @nos i think i got your point.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct orderNode 
{
   int price;
   int quantity;
};

struct lnode
{ 
  struct lnode* next;
  struct lnode* prev;
  struct orderNode* oNode;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `lnode.data` to access an `orderNode` your definition is wrong, it'd have to be:

```
struct lnode
{
   struct orderNode *data;
   ...
```

You can then use `lnode.data->price` or `lnode.data->quantity`, assuming you've assigned the `data` pointer to a valid `orderNode` struct.